# Does the finiteness of $R/P$ imply that of $R/P^r$, where $P$ is a prime ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

> Conjecture:  Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. $P$ be a
>   prime ideal of $R$. If $|R/P|<+\infty$, Then $|R/P^r|<+\infty$ for any
>   integer $r\gt 1$.

$|A|$ denotes the cardinality of the set $A$. $R/I$ denotes the [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)

I think it does not hold. Could anyone give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $R=\Bbb F_2[x_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N]/\langle x_ix_j\,:\, i,j\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $P=\langle\overline x_n\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. $R$ is infinite, $R/P\cong \Bbb F_2$ and $P^2=0$.

Comment: What is $\overline{x_n}$? Are you saying the multivariable polynomial ring with infinite variables over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ?

Comment: $\overline x_n$ is the image of $x_n$ by the quotient map in the quotient ring. $\Bbb F_2[x_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N]$ is the polynomial ring over countable-infinitely many variables with coefficients in $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: In this example, $R=\{ b+\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}{a_i \overline{x_i}}  \mid b,a_i \in \mathbb{F}_2 \}$ and $R/P=\{b \mid b\in \mathbb{F}_2\}= \mathbb{F}_2$. Am I right?

Comment: Actually, $R=\{b+\sum_{i\in \Bbb N} a_i\overline x_i\,:\, b,a_i\in\Bbb F_2\text{ and }\lvert\{i\in\Bbb N\,:\, a_i\ne 0\}\rvert<\infty\}$, or equivalently $R=\{b+\sum_{j=1}^h a_i\overline x_{i_j}\,:\, m,i_1,\cdots,i_h\in\Bbb N\land b,a_i\in \Bbb F_2\}$, but I think you are not shooting far from the point.